# Change Jhipster landing page based on Authority

Tags: jhipster

I have seen that one could change Jhipster landing page by including this,

```
registerAuthenticationSuccess() {
    this.eventManager.subscribe('authenticationSuccess', (message) => {
        this.principal.identity().then((account) => {
         if (account.authorities.indexOf('ROLE_CONTRACTOR') >=0)
        {
            this.router.navigate(['/property']);
        }
        else
        {
            this.account = account;
        }
        });
    });
}
```

in the home.component.ts and call it in the onInit method as,

```
this.principal.identity().then((account) => {
        this.account = account;
    });
    this.registerAuthenticationSuccess();
```

However, in my case, this does not work. In my home page I have defined only admin authority to be able to access the home page in route.ts file as below,

```
export const HOME_ROUTE: Route = {  path: '',  component: HomeComponent, data: {    authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN'],    pageTitle: 'home.title'  },  canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]};
```

But when I log in as a contractor, I am redirected to the sign-in page saying I do not have permission to go to the home page. It does not get redirected to the property page.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, in Jhipster once we sign in it goes to the HomeComponent by default. In your case it is failing because only the ROLE_ADMIN can access the HomeComponent. So obviously it will not allow a user with ROLE_CONTRACTOR to login, it will get redirected to unauthorized page before calling the method where you have written the code for router navigation.

So try by removing the  authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN'] from the route path, so it will allow all the users to access the HomeComponent and if user is with ROLE_CONTRACTOR  it will redirect to property page.

Comment: That does not work, if I allow all roles in home.component it loads the home page without redirecting. I want to redirect based on role before it comes to home page. I tried doing it in the sign-in page, but it does not work.